# Is it possible to configure regexp based virtual hosts using Tomcat?

Tags: tomcat, tomcat6

I want to configure Tomcat6 so that I have one `appBase` answering all requests with hostnames matching `"^www.something.[a-z]+$"` and another `appBase` answering all requests matching say `"^www.(foo|bar).com$"`.

Is it possible to configure such regexp based virtual hosts using Tomcat?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing in Tomcat for that level of flexibility out of the box. I would guess that the closest what you can get are [Host Name Aliases](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/config/host.html#Host_Name_Aliases).

You might want to consider putting Apache + `mod_proxy` in front of Tomcat and do some URL rewriting with `mod_rewrite`. Another alternative is to write your own custom [Valve](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/api/org/apache/catalina/Valve.html).